# javascript variables loaded from server are not defined in chrome but firefox

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, django-templates

After **form** data input the data will be processed on server. The result will be responded immediately to client on same site where the data were entered. The tool "visualize.js" needs the result to visualize.
view.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
   //data processing ...
   return render(request, 'data_input.html',{'n':n,'t':t,'f':f,'s':s})
```

data_input.html:

```
        <script  type='text/javascript'>
        var n_value = {{n}}; //to be visualized
        var t_value = {{t}}; //to be visualized
        var f_value = {{f}}; //to be visualized
        var s_value = {{s}}; //to be visualized
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src ="{% static "visualize.js" %}" ></script>
```

In firefox the variables can be found and visualized by the external tool "visualize.js" but in chrome they seem not to be defined with the error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined** 
I also tried some code tricks like "visualize.js" should be loaded after the result is there but no success.

Any idea I could try? Thank you.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, `<script type='text/javascript' src ="{% static "visualize.js" %}" ></script>` is suppose to include the visualize.js into the page? If that is the case, it has to come before your script and you need to declare n,t,f,s before using them, I will asume visualize does this part.

Comment: I also tried that n,t,f,s are declared first before the result is there. But visualize.js only sees the initialized values and not the computed values. The logic is clear that at first the variables must be loaded or defined before visualize.js can use them.

Comment: I dont know what visualize.js does, also I don't know what sort of templating you use since the way you include visualize.js into your document is not a standard html. 

Try to add alert("somealert") or console.log("sometext") in different parts of the script to determin the order it is fired on. A variable must be declared before it can be referenced, and this is the error you are getting.

Comment: The issue, in a way I see it is, that you are attempting to define an object named n_value, and then within it I got no idea what the other {} is for, without them though I do get the same issue you do. And in this case the reason is beacause your key "n" doesn't reference anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I already mentioned that my javascript visualization tool only worked in firefox and not in google chrome. After I tried a lot I found this solution:

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
var n_value = {{n|safe}}; //to be visualized
var t_value = {{t|safe}}; //to be visualized
var f_value = {{f|safe}}; //to be visualized
var s_value = {{s|safe}}; //to be visualized
</script>
```

**safe** has to be used.